# LED Controller Circuit Design with BJT

Tags: transistors, led, bjt, npn, led-driver

https://www.circuitlab.com/circuit/mthven79a2m6/led-controller/
I designed a LED controller to turn the led on/off. What do u think about my design?

Comment: Please embed your picture into the question.

Comment: If you don't explain why the components are there, I'd just say you can remove the transistor and two resistors.

Comment: If you really want to **learn** something about electronics, do not enter this site for ask this kind of question. It prevents yourself the power of the experience. Get yourself a breadboard, a few LEDs, some transistors, resistors, and a bunch of colour jumpers, and try building this circuit yourself, and see if the LED really get on. Please DON'T try to learn about basic circuits like this one with a computer simulation, this is the worst thing that you could do. And, by the way, in this circuit shown the LED will be on all the time.